# Use Azure Vault Secret from onpremise Web Application

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-keyvault

I would like to use an Azure Key Vault secret from an on-premise web application.

I created a Key Vault with a Secret, but in Access Policies I should specify an Authorized Application and in the samples is used an Azure WebApp.

I want instead use the Secret from on-premise MVC web app: shoud i specify nothing and it works ? i specified the Azure Vault and as Principal myself but i'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, something will need to authenticate to access the secret.
Either the current user, or you can use a service principal.

Since we are talking about an MVC app, the service principal is probably easier.
You will need to register a new app in Azure Active Directory via the Azure Portal.
Find Azure AD, and register a new app via App registrations.

The name and URLs don't really matter, but it needs to be of type Web app/API.
The sign-on URL can be `https://localhost` for example.
Then add a *key* in the *Keys* blade to the app (click Settings after the app is created, then Keys).
Copy the client id (application id) and the key somewhere.

Now you can go to your Key Vault, and create a new access policy, and choose the app you created as the principal.
Give it the rights you want, like Secrets -> Get.
Then you can save the policy.

In your app, you can then use the [Key Vault library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault) + [ADAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) like so:

```
var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
{
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var credential = new ClientCredential("client-id-here", "key-here");
    AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
    return result.AccessToken;
});

SecretBundle secret = await kvClient.GetSecretAsync("https://yourvault.vault.azure.net/", "secret-name");
string secretValue = secret.Value;
```

Comment: In AcquireTokenAsync i got ""AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided."
I tried the name of the key and his hidden value for the key, the client id is the Application ID from AD ->registrations->app: the on premise app and the fake azure app are both with auth on SQL , not windows auth

Comment: You should put the key value which gets hidden after you leave the blade. There has to be some problem with that. Try making a new "password" (=client secret) and use that. The application id is correct. Make sure there's no extra spaces etc.

Comment: I was not registering the app in the Azure subscription and using a wrong value for the client secret: now it works. Thanks.

Comment: woah you save my day! Thanks @juunas

Comment: Now instead of having the secret directly in your code you have it in Key Vault and you have the client credentials to access Key Vault in your code. It is just shifting the problem, is'nt it ?

Comment: Very true. For that in Azure you can use a Managed Identity.

Comment: You can also use a client certificate and not store the secret in the web app at all.

Comment: Thank you for this code!  This worked for me and was much faster starting up than using Azure Managed Identity.  All I needed to do was store the client_secret in the App Settings Configuration.