# Best way to access values from AzureKeyVault

Tags: azure

I am using an On-Prem application. Planning to migrate all my secrets to the azure key vault. I am using asp.net core 3.1 Framework can somebody suggest the best way to access the secrets through code if am using on-prem application and not deploying the application to azure.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your key vault is publicly accessible over the internet or assuming you have extended your private network to Azure you can access Azure key vault for on-premise applications.

There is another thread on SO which describes an approach for this problem statement - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904715/use-azure-vault-secret-from-onpremise-web-application)